# Adding the force-ssl package to Meteor project already using appcache

Tags: node.js, caching, ssl, meteor, websocket

I have a Meteor project which is using the appcache package to keep a cache of the Meteor app in the browser. Now I have purchased an SSL certificate and would like to start forcing users to connect to the https:// address for the site. So I add the force-ssl package. However, when a user goes to http://example.com the cached version of the Meteor app loads, it gets the cache-update notice, and attempts to start downloading the new version of the app. So the http:// site is now trying to request resources from the https:// site and the browser blocks this because of CORS issues.

I've played with the force-ssl package a bit, even tried to set some headers:

```
var host = url.parse(Meteor.absoluteUrl()).hostname;
res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', 'http://' + host);
res.setHeader('access-control-allow-credentials', 'true');
res.setHeader('access-control-allow-methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
```

But I am still seeing CORS errors like these:

```
GET https://www.example.com/sockjs/881/y6to3ysz/xhr 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Anyone know how to set the headers properly so that the update can go through from the https:// to the http:// site? I'm going down the rabbit hole on setting socksjs headers etc and figured maybe someone has already done this and might save me some time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you cannot serve the SSL certificate from the node server so the standard solution in production is to set up a proxy server (NGINX in my case) to handle the certificate and then forward to meteor.  I also discovered after some frustration that I needed to remove the force-ssl package in order to forward from a proxy.

[Here is a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936433/deploying-meteor-to-production-with-meteor-up-ssl-and-nginx/26939568#26939568) I started and later posted the above solution to on this point.

The appcache package worked normally & as expected for me throughout this process. It should start getting served from https.  But assuming it is sticking, and if your app is not in production use (because each user would encounter the same problem), you could manually remove the http cache (in chrome it is located at `chrome://appcache-internals`).  Hope this helps.